# How to get PageIndex of selected page in RadGrid in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get PageIndex of selected  page in RadGrid in asp.net?
I have a radgrid with pager. When I selected a page number , programm go to ItemCommand event of radgrid. How I can get index of selected page?
please fill ..... in below code

My code:

```
protected void radGridBIGetList_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string strCmndName = e.CommandName.ToString();
    if (strCmndName == "Page")
    { 

        GridPagerItem selectedPage = (GridPagerItem)e.Item;
        int pageIndex = .....;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to read pageindex when grid is posted back our in client browser there are two different rules.

Comment: When radgrid is created , when I clicked in page number (as 2) event fo ItemCommand is called

Comment: I want to read pageindex in this step

Comment: please learn me this tow rules

Comment: excuse me for late respond I am busy at the time I will post a nice answer today ;)

Comment: @saeed you are bad :|